# Grabbing data with relations. 1 big query or afew small queries

Tags: php, mysql, performance, code-readability

Suppose I have a table structure like

[image]

I want to grab all user metas

is it better to do a big query joining all tables in the image ...

```
SELECT [columns ...] FROM usermetasections LEFT JOIN usermetakeys ON ...
LEFT JOIN usermetas ON ...
LEFT JOIN users ON ...
WHERE users.id = xxx
```

...

... or break them into smaller queries like ...

```
Loop through SELECT * FROM usermetasections
    Loop through SELECT * FROM usermetakeys WHERE section = xxx
        Loop thought SELECT * FROM usermetas WHERE key = xxx AND user = xxx
```

I think if I go the 1st approach, it will be faster for "machine" performance but bad for developer performance? harder to read, more code to parse queries into PHP objects?

Answer (score 4):

Usually, you **let the database itself do the joining**. That's what a relational database management system is made for. It contains countless optimizations that will perform better than your average application code.

Sometimes that does indeed create a lot of overhead in regards to information being sent over the network (say, you loop over 1000 records, and only if a few complex conditions are met, you need the info from the other table) in which case you could let your application-code do the join, but even then you can just re-query with `SELECT yourfields FROM yourtables-joined WHERE yourtable.id IN (list,of,IDs)`

Comment: +1 for `where yourtable.id in (list, of, ids)`. There's no need to perform a query in a loop.